# Как добавить колонки в БД sqlite3 (python flask_sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlite3, flask-sqlalchemy

Есть код на python с моделью пользователя типа:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
```

Теперь необходимо добавить еще пару колонок, чтобы стало так (например):

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    blabla = db.Column(db.String(20), default='')
```

**Вопрос: Как добавить эти колонки (без удаления БД), причем так, чтобы поля обязательные (`nullable=False`) и по умолчанию `default=random()` (например) появились с новыми устновленными значениями**.

*P.S. В той же БД хранится еще одна таблица и все создавалось автоматически через flask_sqlalchemy*

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `миграции`

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD created_on integer NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE user ADD blabla text NOT NULL;
```

created_on - integer так как sqlite3 не имеет тип DateTime, переводите в timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйся скриптом миграции, например Alembic. Это библиотека Python, запуск примерно такой для создания миграционной модели:

```
python -m alembic revision --autogenerate
```

и такой, для вывода модели в базу:

```
python -m alembic upgrade head
```

Но перед этим обязательно настрой Alembic xthtp *.env* файл. Об этом можно в репозитории почитать.